# InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found. Incompatible shapes in Tensorflow text-classification model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, text-classification

I am trying to get code working from the following [repo](https://github.com/YanWenqiang/HBLSTM-CRF/blob/master/HBLSTM-CRF.py), which is based off this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.04250.pdf). It had a lot of errors, but I mostly got it working. However, I keep getting the same problem and I really do not understand how to troubleshoot this/what is even going wrong.

The error occurs the second time the validation if statement critera is met. The first time is always works, then breaks on the second. I'm including the output it prints before breaking if its helpful. See error below:

```html
step = 1, train_loss = 1204.7784423828125, train_accuracy = 0.13725490868091583
counter = 1, dev_loss = 1188.6639287274584, dev_accuacy = 0.2814199453625912
step = 2, train_loss = 1000.983154296875, train_accuracy = 0.26249998807907104
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1364     try:
-> 1365       return fn(*args)
   1366     except errors.OpError as e:

7 frames
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [2,185] vs. [2,229]
  [[{{node loss/cond/add_1}}]]
  [[viterbi_decode/cond/rnn_1/while/Switch_3/_541]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [2,185] vs. [2,229]
  [[{{node loss/cond/add_1}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1382                     '\nsession_config.graph_options.rewrite_options.'
   1383                     'disable_meta_optimizer = True')
-> 1384       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1385 
   1386   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [2,185] vs. [2,229]
  [[node loss/cond/add_1 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
  [[viterbi_decode/cond/rnn_1/while/Switch_3/_541]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [2,185] vs. [2,229]
  [[node loss/cond/add_1 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

Original stack trace for 'loss/cond/add_1':
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 664, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-11-90859dc83f76>", line 66, in <module>
    main()
  File "<ipython-input-11-90859dc83f76>", line 12, in main
    model = DAModel()
  File "<ipython-input-9-682db36e2a23>", line 148, in __init__
    self.logits, self.labels, self.dialogue_lengths)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/contrib/crf/python/ops/crf.py", line 257, in crf_log_likelihood
    transition_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/contrib/crf/python/ops/crf.py", line 116, in crf_sequence_score
    false_fn=_multi_seq_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/layers/utils.py", line 202, in smart_cond
    pred, true_fn=true_fn, false_fn=false_fn, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/smart_cond.py", line 59, in smart_cond
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1235, in cond
    orig_res_f, res_f = context_f.BuildCondBranch(false_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1061, in BuildCondBranch
    original_result = fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/contrib/crf/python/ops/crf.py", line 104, in _multi_seq_fn
    unary_scores = crf_unary_score(tag_indices, sequence_lengths, inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/contrib/crf/python/ops/crf.py", line 287, in crf_unary_score
    flattened_tag_indices = array_ops.reshape(offsets + tag_indices, [-1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 899, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1197, in _add_dispatch
    return gen_math_ops.add_v2(x, y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 549, in add_v2
    "AddV2", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 794, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3357, in create_op
    attrs, op_def, compute_device)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3426, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1748, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

Here is the code (which is slightly different from the repo in order to get it to run:

Versions:
Python 3

tensorflow == 1.15.0

pandas == 0.25.3

numpy == 1.17.5

```html
import glob
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# preprocess data

file_list = []
for f in glob.glob('swda/*'):
  file_list.append(f)

df_list = []
for i in file_list:
  df = pd.read_csv(i)
  df_list.append(df)

text_list = []
label_list = []

for df in df_list:
  df['utterance_no_specialchar_'] = df.utterance_no_specialchar.astype(str)
  text = df.utterance_no_specialchar_.tolist()
  labels = df.da_category.tolist()
  text_list.append(text)
  label_list.append(labels)

### new preprocessing step  
text_list = [[[j] for j in i] for i in text_list]

tok_data = [y[0] for x in text_list for y in x]

tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(tok_data)

sequences = []
for x in text_list:
  tmp = []
  for y in x:
    tmp.append(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(y)[0])
  sequences.append(tmp)

def _pad_sequences(sequences, pad_tok, max_length):
    """
    Args:
        sequences: a generator of list or tuple
        pad_tok: the char to pad with
    Returns:
        a list of list where each sublist has same length
    """
    sequence_padded, sequence_length = [], []

    for seq in sequences:
        seq = list(seq)
        seq_ = seq[:max_length] + [pad_tok]*max(max_length - len(seq), 0)
        sequence_padded +=  [seq_]
        sequence_length += [min(len(seq), max_length)]

    return sequence_padded, sequence_length

def pad_sequences(sequences, pad_tok, nlevels=1):
    """
    Args:
        sequences: a generator of list or tuple
        pad_tok: the char to pad with
        nlevels: "depth" of padding, for the case where we have characters ids
    Returns:
        a list of list where each sublist has same length
    """
    if nlevels == 1:
        max_length = max(map(lambda x : len(x), sequences))
        sequence_padded, sequence_length = _pad_sequences(sequences,
                                            pad_tok, max_length)

    elif nlevels == 2:
        max_length_word = max([max(map(lambda x: len(x), seq))
                               for seq in sequences])
        sequence_padded, sequence_length = [], []
        for seq in sequences:
            # all words are same length now
            sp, sl = _pad_sequences(seq, pad_tok, max_length_word)
            sequence_padded += [sp]
            sequence_length += [sl]

        max_length_sentence = max(map(lambda x : len(x), sequences))
        
        sequence_padded, _ = _pad_sequences(sequence_padded,
                [pad_tok]*max_length_word, max_length_sentence)
        sequence_length, _ = _pad_sequences(sequence_length, 0,
                max_length_sentence)

    return sequence_padded, sequence_length

def minibatches(data, labels, batch_size):
  data_size = len(data)
  start_index = 0

  num_batches_per_epoch = int((len(data) + batch_size - 1) / batch_size)
  for batch_num in range(num_batches_per_epoch):
      start_index = batch_num * batch_size
      end_index = min((batch_num + 1) * batch_size, data_size)
      yield data[start_index: end_index], labels[start_index: end_index]

def select(parameters, length):
  """Select the last valid time step output as the sentence embedding
  :params parameters: [batch, seq_len, hidden_dims]
  :params length: [batch]
  :Returns : [batch, hidden_dims]
  """
  shape = tf.shape(parameters)
  idx = tf.range(shape[0])
  idx = tf.stack([idx, length - 1], axis = 1)
  return tf.gather_nd(parameters, idx)


class DAModel():
    def __init__(self):
        with tf.variable_scope("placeholder"):

            self.dialogue_lengths = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = [None], name = "dialogue_lengths")
            self.word_ids = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = [None,None,None], name = "word_ids")
            self.utterance_lengths = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = [None, None], name = "utterance_lengths")
            self.labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = [None, None], name = "labels")
            self.clip = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [], name = 'clip')

######################## EMBEDDINGS ###########################################

        with tf.variable_scope("embeddings"):
            _word_embeddings = tf.get_variable(
                name = "_word_embeddings",
                dtype = tf.float32,
                shape = [words, word_dim],
                initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer()
                )
            word_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(_word_embeddings,self.word_ids, name="word_embeddings")
            self.word_embeddings = tf.nn.dropout(word_embeddings, 0.8)
                    
        with tf.variable_scope("utterance_encoder"):
            s = tf.shape(self.word_embeddings)
            batch_size = s[0] * s[1]
            
            time_step = s[-2]
            word_embeddings = tf.reshape(self.word_embeddings, [batch_size, time_step, word_dim])
            length = tf.reshape(self.utterance_lengths, [batch_size])

            fw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(hidden_size_lstm_1, forget_bias=0.8, state_is_tuple= True)
            bw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(hidden_size_lstm_1, forget_bias=0.8, state_is_tuple= True)
            
            output, _ = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(fw, bw, word_embeddings,sequence_length=length, dtype = tf.float32)
            output = tf.concat(output, axis = -1) # [batch_size, time_step, dim]
            # Select the last valid time step output as the utterance embedding, 
            # this method is more concise than TensorArray with while_loop
            # output = select(output, self.utterance_lengths) # [batch_size, dim]
            output = select(output, length) # [batch_size, dim]

            # output = tf.reshape(output, s[0], s[1], 2 * hidden_size_lstm_1)
            output = tf.reshape(output, [s[0], s[1], 2 * hidden_size_lstm_1])

            output = tf.nn.dropout(output, 0.8)

        with tf.variable_scope("bi-lstm"):
            cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size_lstm_2, state_is_tuple = True)
            cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size_lstm_2, state_is_tuple = True)
            
            (output_fw, output_bw), _ = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw, cell_bw, output, sequence_length = self.dialogue_lengths, dtype = tf.float32)
            outputs = tf.concat([output_fw, output_bw], axis = -1)
            outputs = tf.nn.dropout(outputs, 0.8)
        
        with tf.variable_scope("proj1"):
            output = tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, 2 * hidden_size_lstm_2])
            W = tf.get_variable("W", dtype = tf.float32, shape = [2 * hidden_size_lstm_2, proj1], initializer= tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
            b = tf.get_variable("b", dtype = tf.float32, shape = [proj1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
            output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(output, W) + b)

        with tf.variable_scope("proj2"):
            W = tf.get_variable("W", dtype = tf.float32, shape = [proj1, proj2], initializer= tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
            b = tf.get_variable("b", dtype = tf.float32, shape = [proj2], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
            output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(output, W) + b)

        with tf.variable_scope("logits"):
            nstep = tf.shape(outputs)[1]
            W = tf.get_variable("W", dtype = tf.float32,shape=[proj2, tags], initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer())
            b = tf.get_variable("b", dtype = tf.float32,shape = [tags],initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

            pred = tf.matmul(output, W) + b
            self.logits = tf.reshape(pred, [-1, nstep, tags])
        
        with tf.variable_scope("loss"):
            log_likelihood, self.trans_params = tf.contrib.crf.crf_log_likelihood(
                        self.logits, self.labels, self.dialogue_lengths)
            self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(-log_likelihood) + tf.nn.l2_loss(W) + tf.nn.l2_loss(b)
            #tf.summary.scalar("loss", self.loss)
        

        with tf.variable_scope("viterbi_decode"):
            viterbi_sequence, _ = tf.contrib.crf.crf_decode(self.logits, self.trans_params,  self.dialogue_lengths)
            
            batch_size = tf.shape(self.dialogue_lengths)[0]

            output_ta = tf.TensorArray(dtype = tf.float32, size = 1, dynamic_size = True)
            def body(time, output_ta_1):
                length = self.dialogue_lengths[time]
                vcode = viterbi_sequence[time][:length]
                true_labs = self.labels[time][:length]
                accurate = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.equal(vcode, true_labs), tf.float32))

                output_ta_1 = output_ta_1.write(time, accurate)
                return time + 1, output_ta_1


            def condition(time, output_ta_1):
                return time < batch_size

            i = 0
            [time, output_ta] = tf.while_loop(condition, body, loop_vars = [i, output_ta])
            output_ta = output_ta.stack()
            accuracy = tf.reduce_sum(output_ta)
            self.accuracy = accuracy / tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(self.dialogue_lengths, tf.float32))
            #tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", self.accuracy)

        with tf.variable_scope("train_op"):
            optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.1)
            #if tf.greater(self.clip , 0):
            grads, vs = zip(*optimizer.compute_gradients(self.loss))
            grads, gnorm = tf.clip_by_global_norm(grads, self.clip)
            self.train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, vs))
            #else:
            #    self.train_op = optimizer.minimize(self.loss)
        #self.merged = tf.summary.merge_all()


### Set model variables

hidden_size_lstm_1 = 200
hidden_size_lstm_2 = 200
tags = 39 # assuming number of classes to predict?
word_dim = 300
proj1 = 200
proj2 = 100
words = 20001 
# words = 8759 + 1 # max(num_unique_word_tokens)
batchSize = 2
log_dir = "train"
model_dir = "DAModel"
model_name = "ckpt"

### Run model

def main():
    # tokenize and vectorize text data to prepare for embedding
    train_data = sequences[:75]
    train_labels = label_list[:75]
    dev_data = sequences[75:]
    dev_labels = label_list[75:]
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.4
    
    with tf.Session(config = config) as sess:
        model = DAModel()
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        clip = 2
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        #writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("D:\\Experimemts\\tensorflow\\DA\\train", sess.graph)
        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("train", sess.graph)
        counter = 0
        for epoch in range(10):
            for dialogues, labels in minibatches(train_data, train_labels, batchSize):
                _, dialogue_lengthss = pad_sequences(dialogues, 0)
                word_idss, utterance_lengthss = pad_sequences(dialogues, 0, nlevels = 2)
                true_labs = labels
                labs_t, _ = pad_sequences(true_labs, 0)
                counter += 1
                train_loss, train_accuracy, _ = sess.run([model.loss, model.accuracy,model.train_op], feed_dict = {model.word_ids: word_idss, model.utterance_lengths: utterance_lengthss, model.dialogue_lengths: dialogue_lengthss, model.labels:labs_t, model.clip :clip} )
                #writer.add_summary(summary, global_step = counter)
                print("step = {}, train_loss = {}, train_accuracy = {}".format(counter, train_loss, train_accuracy))
                
                train_precision_summ = tf.Summary()
                train_precision_summ.value.add(
                    tag='train_accuracy', simple_value=train_accuracy)
                writer.add_summary(train_precision_summ, counter)

                train_loss_summ = tf.Summary()
                train_loss_summ.value.add(
                    tag='train_loss', simple_value=train_loss)
                writer.add_summary(train_loss_summ, counter)
                
                if counter % 1 == 0:
                    loss_dev = []
                    acc_dev = []
                    for dev_dialogues, dev_labels in minibatches(dev_data, dev_labels, batchSize):
                        _, dialogue_lengthss = pad_sequences(dev_dialogues, 0)
                        word_idss, utterance_lengthss = pad_sequences(dev_dialogues, 0, nlevels = 2)
                        true_labs = dev_labels
                        labs_t, _ = pad_sequences(true_labs, 0)
                        dev_loss, dev_accuacy = sess.run([model.loss, model.accuracy], feed_dict = {model.word_ids: word_idss, model.utterance_lengths: utterance_lengthss, model.dialogue_lengths: dialogue_lengthss, model.labels:labs_t})
                        loss_dev.append(dev_loss)
                        acc_dev.append(dev_accuacy)
                    valid_loss = sum(loss_dev) / len(loss_dev)
                    valid_accuracy = sum(acc_dev) / len(acc_dev)

                    dev_precision_summ = tf.Summary()
                    dev_precision_summ.value.add(
                        tag='dev_accuracy', simple_value=valid_accuracy)
                    writer.add_summary(dev_precision_summ, counter)

                    dev_loss_summ = tf.Summary()
                    dev_loss_summ.value.add(
                        tag='dev_loss', simple_value=valid_loss)
                    writer.add_summary(dev_loss_summ, counter)
                    print("counter = {}, dev_loss = {}, dev_accuacy = {}".format(counter, valid_loss, valid_accuracy))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    main()
```

The data comes from [here](https://github.com/cgpotts/swda) and looks like this:

```html
[[['what  '],
 ['do you want to start '],
 ['f uh  laughter  you hit  you hit  f uh   '],
 ['it doesnt matter  '],
 ['f um  were discussing the capital punishment i believe '],
 ['right  '],
 ['you are right  '],
 ['yeah  '],
 ['  i  i  suppose i should have '],
 ['f uh  which  '],
 ['i  am  am  pro capital punishment except that i dont like the way its done '],
 ['uhhuh  '],
 ['f uh  yeah  '],
 ['f uh   i  f uh  i  guess  i  i  hate to see anyone die f uh   ']
 ...
 ]]
```

The dataset to train the model can be found here:
https://github.com/cmeaton/Hierarchical_BiLSTM-CRF_Encoder/tree/master/swda_parsed

I'm having a hard time understanding what this error even means and how to approach understanding it. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is this speech recognition? And what's `data_list` and `label_list` variables? I know you've given data for one (probably `label_list`) but is there any way to get some samples for the other?

Comment: @thushv89 Thanks. This is not speech recognition, it is dialogue act classification. 'sequences' is what I use as my X. It is the tokenized text data. label_list is my y, the classes I am trying to predict.  A sample of each are provided in the gist above.

Comment: Thanks for the data. Can you actually reduce the size of the data (to may be 10 samples) and format it. Having trouble copying and pasting due to indentation problems.

Comment: @thushv89 No problem, I updated the gist link. It includes 2 items of text/token data and their labels, limited to 5 samples each.

Comment: @connor449 The error is not reproducible. Could you please provide a minimal code that reproduces the error with the sample of your data?

Comment: @rvinas Thanks for looking into it. I am surprised you're not getting the same error. Please use the full dataset, which you can place in a directory to feed into the model in the `file_list` code at the beginning using `glob`. I also edited to include my imports and library versions, should that be an issue. All the code I included is necessary to run the model.

Comment: @connor449 Which operating system are you running the code on ?

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos I'm on Windows 10

Comment: have you checked the shape of your input data X and Y? i had a smiliar error when i had different shapes for my data and label. Example X(None,1024,1) Y(None,512,1) that lead to smiliar error. When i changed my input Y to the same shape, It worked

Answer (score 2):

### Introduction

I think the main problem is a data mismatch in the sizes of the arrays (or matrixes or other structure) you are feeding `sess.run`. Specifically when you are calling:

`train_loss, train_accuracy, _ = sess.run([model.loss, model.accuracy,model.train_op], feed_dict = {model.word_ids: word_idss, model.utterance_lengths: utterance_lengthss, model.dialogue_lengths: dialogue_lengthss, model.labels:labs_t, model.clip :clip} )`

And more specifically, this error here hints that it's a mismatch problem:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 
indices[317] = [317, -1] does not index into param shape [318,39,400]
             [[{{node utterance_encoder/GatherNd}}]]
```

**I considered maybe that running on a fresh install might result in a error-free run.**

I am getting similar errors but also a whole list of warnings.
Please note I am running on windows 7 and using python 3.6.1.

---

### Versions

I have tried the following tensorflow versions but with no success:

- tf 1.15
- tf 1.14
- tf 1.13.1
- tf 1.12
- tf 1.11
- tf 1.10
- tf 1.10 with downgraded keras to 2.2.1

---

### Steps

- Installed python 3.6.1 (supported version of tensorflow). Installed for All Users. Set the Path. Installed in C:\Python36
- pip3 install --user --upgrade tensorflow==1.15
- pip3 install --user --upgrade pandas == 0.25.3
- pip3 install --user --upgrade numpy == 1.17.5
- Download the following: https://github.com/cmeaton/Hierarchical_BiLSTM-CRF_Encoder/tree/master/swda_parsed
- Run the provided code

---

### Result (Includes Many Warnings)

I think the following might be important:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[317] = [317, -1] does not index into param shape [318,39,400]
         [[{{node utterance_encoder/GatherNd}}]]
```

### Full Trace

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From test.py:313: The name tf.reset_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From test.py:256: The name tf.ConfigProto is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From test.py:259: The name tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session instead.

2020-01-31 12:13:10.096283: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
WARNING:tensorflow:From test.py:119: The name tf.variable_scope is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.variable_scope instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From test.py:121: The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From test.py:130: The name tf.get_variable is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_variable instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From test.py:137: calling dropout (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) with keep_prob is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `rate` instead of `keep_prob`. Rate should be set to `rate = 1 - keep_prob`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From test.py:147: LSTMCell.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
This class is equivalent as tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell, and will be replaced by that in Tensorflow 2.0.
WARNING:tensorflow:From test.py:150: bidirectional_dynamic_rnn (from tensorflow.python.ops.rnn) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.RNN(cell))`, which is equivalent to this API
WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\rnn.py:464: dynamic_rnn (from tensorflow.python.ops.rnn) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `keras.layers.RNN(cell)`, which is equivalent to this API
WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py:958: Layer.add_variable (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `layer.add_weight` method instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py:962: calling Zeros.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Call initializer instance with the dtype argument instead of passing it to the constructor
WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\rnn.py:244: where (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
WARNING:tensorflow:
The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops)
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

WARNING:tensorflow:From test.py:163: BasicLSTMCell.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
This class is equivalent as tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell, and will be replaced by that in Tensorflow 2.0.
WARNING:tensorflow:From test.py:223: The name tf.train.AdagradOptimizer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.AdagradOptimizer instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\adagrad.py:76: calling Constant.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Call initializer instance with the dtype argument instead of passing it to the constructor
WARNING:tensorflow:From test.py:261: The name tf.global_variables_initializer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From test.py:263: The name tf.train.Saver is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.Saver instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From test.py:265: The name tf.summary.FileWriter is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter instead.

2020-01-31 12:13:16.563989: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at gather_nd_op.cc:47 : Invalid argument: indices[317] = [317, -1] does not index into param shape [318,39,400]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1365, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1350, in _run_fn
    target_list, run_metadata)
  File "D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1443, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[317] = [317, -1] does not index into param shape [318,39,400]
         [[{{node utterance_encoder/GatherNd}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 314, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 274, in main
    train_loss, train_accuracy, _ = sess.run([model.loss, model.accuracy,model.train_op], feed_dict = {model.word_ids: word_idss, model.utterance_lengths: utterance_lengthss, model.dialogue_lengths: dialogue_lengthss, model.labels:labs_t, model.clip :clip} )
  File "D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 956, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1180, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1359, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1384, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[317] = [317, -1] does not index into param shape [318,39,400]
         [[node utterance_encoder/GatherNd (defined at D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1748) ]]

Original stack trace for 'utterance_encoder/GatherNd':
  File "test.py", line 314, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 260, in main
    model = DAModel()
  File "test.py", line 155, in __init__
    output = select(output, length) # [batch_size, dim]
  File "test.py", line 114, in select
    return tf.gather_nd(parameters, idx)
  File "D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\dispatch.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 4277, in gather_nd
    return gen_array_ops.gather_nd(params, indices, name=name)
  File "D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 3975, in gather_nd
    "GatherNd", params=params, indices=indices, name=name)
  File "D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 794, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 3357, in create_op
    attrs, op_def, compute_device)
  File "D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 3426, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "D:\Users\bakopme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 1748, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's focus on the error:

```
Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [2,185] vs. [2,229]
```

The problem seems to be that an operation between two tensors fails, because their shapes are incompatible.

---

It's possible that the `tensorflow` version you've selected is less permissive than the one used by the author.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/YanWenqiang/HBLSTM-CRF/issues/3), the author guesses he used `tensorflow==1.8`.

So first I would suggest you try to use this earlier version, or others before\after that (1.7, 1.9, 1.10 etc).

---

Also, earlier versions may not have the `keras` package integrated to them as it is today, so you may want to use a specific `keras` version as well.

For example according to [this issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11749), what helped was to downgrade to `keras==2.2.2`.

---

If that doesn't help, maybe one of these will: [1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29489), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42822844/4960855), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35138131/4960855), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34822219/4960855), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55574929/4960855), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49894211/4960855)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I downgraded to tensorflow==1.8 and keras==2.2.0 and same error